# Cannot create record when LWC input fields populated from Google chrome save address

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience

I cannot create a new Case record when the custom LWC input fields, to capture the address, are populated from the Google Chrome browser saved address. I am getting the below error when I click on the Continue button.

[image]

I am aware of this error, and usually, we would get it when the User doesn't have access to the respective object or create record permissions. But, with the same user credentials, I can create a new record successfully when I input values manually or select any existing record on the component.

I couldn't find any issue with code and **getHasInvalidFields**() seems working fine in all other case. I have done some research regarding the issue but didn't find any solution specific to this issue. Could you please help me if anyone has thoughts on this?

**Create shipping Address component controller**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import dxMessageChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/dxMessageChannel__c';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import COUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Shipping_Address__c.Country__c';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import saveAddressRecord from '@salesforce/apex/portalGetCaseRecord.createShippingAddressMyAccount';

export default class CreateShippingAddress extends LightningElement {
    @api textReturnAddress
    @api textSaveButton
    @api textCompanyName
    @api textReqCompanyName
    @api textAddressLine1
    @api textReqAddressLine1
    @api textAddressLine2
    @api textAddressLine3
    @api textTownCity
    @api textReqTownCity
    @api textPostalZip
    @api textReqPostalZip
    @api textCompanyCountry
    @api textReqCountry
    @api textExistingAddress

    pickListValues;
    hasInvalidFields;
    showSaveButton = false;
    buttonDisabled = true;

    @track shippingRecord = {Name:'',Address_Line_1__c:'',Address_Line_2__c:'',Address_Line_3__c:'',County__c:'',Post_Code__c:'',Country__c:''};

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    // Get the Record ID from the URL
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
        setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
            this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
            this.currentPage = currentPageReference.attributes.name;
            this.myRecordId = this.currentPageReference?.state?.c__recordId;
            if(this.currentPage === 'My_Account__c') {
                this.showSaveButton = true;
            } else {
                this.showSaveButton = false;
            }
        }        

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName: COUNTRY_FIELD })
    setObjectInfo({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.pickListValues = data.values;
        }
    }    

    hideScreen(){
        this.sendGlobalMessage(null, 'AddressSwitch');
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showlist'));
    }

    handleNewAddress(event){
        // If on the my account page we can save the record directly as its not part 
        // of the create case journey.
        this.hasInvalidFields = this.getHasInvalidFields();
        if(event.target.name === 'companyName'){
            this.shippingRecord.Name = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'address1'){
            this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_1__c = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'address2'){
            this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_2__c= event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'address3'){
            this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_3__c = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'city'){
            this.shippingRecord.Town = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'zipcode'){
            this.shippingRecord.Address__PostalCode__s = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'country'){
            this.shippingRecord.Country__c = event.target.value;
        }
        if(this.shippingRecord.Country__c === '') this.hasInvalidFields = true;
        if (this.hasInvalidFields === false) {
            if(this.currentPage !== 'My_Account__c') {
                this.sendGlobalMessage(JSON.stringify(this.shippingRecord), 'ShippingManualInputted');
            } else {
                this.buttonDisabled = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(this.currentPage === 'My_Account__c') {
                this.buttonDisabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    saveAddressRecord() {
        saveAddressRecord({
            Address1:this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_1__c,
            Address2:this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_2__c,
            Address3:this.shippingRecord.Address_Line_3__c,
            town:this.shippingRecord.Town,
            zipcode:this.shippingRecord.Address__PostalCode__s,
            country:this.shippingRecord.Country__c,
            companyName:this.shippingRecord.Name
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.hideScreen();
        })         
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }

    sendGlobalMessage(theData, process){
        const message = {
            userSelected: theData,
            processIndicator: process
        }
        publish(this.messageContext, dxMessageChannel, message);
    }

      getHasInvalidFields() {
          const inputComponents = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')];
          // Trigger fields validation
          inputComponents.forEach((inputComponent) => {
              inputComponent.reportValidity();
          });
          this.hasInvalidFields = inputComponents.some((inputComponent) => inputComponent.checkValidity() === false);
          return this.hasInvalidFields;
      }    

}
```

---

```
<template>
    <div class="componentSpacing">
        <div class="textHead">{textReturnAddress}</div>
        <div if:true={showSaveButton}>
            <button
                class="slds-button slds-button_text-destructive slds-float_left slds-p-left_medium slds-p-right_medium slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-p-top_xx-small buttonBordered buttonSolid saveButton"
                onclick={saveAddressRecord} disabled={buttonDisabled}>{textSaveButton}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium ">
            <div class="slds-box slds-var-p-around_large caseBox">
                <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound ">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <div>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders" for="input-01">{textCompanyName}</label>
                            <div>
                                <lightning-input type="text" id="input-01" placeholder="e.g megger" name="companyName"
                                    class="Myinput" required message-when-value-missing={textReqCompanyName}
                                    onkeyup={handleNewAddress}>
                                </lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders"
                                for="input-02">{textAddressLine1}</label>
                            <div>
                                <lightning-input type="text" id="input-02" placeholder="e.g 58 My Street"
                                    name="address1" class="Myinput" required
                                    message-when-value-missing={textReqAddressLine1} onkeyup={handleNewAddress}>
                                </lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders"
                                for="input-03">{textAddressLine2}</label>
                            <div>
                                <lightning-input type="text" id="input-03" placeholder="e.g street 34" name="address2"
                                    class="Myinput" onkeyup={handleNewAddress}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders"
                                for="input-04">{textAddressLine3}</label>
                            <div>
                                <lightning-input type="text" id="input-04" placeholder="e.g street 12" name="address3"
                                    class="Myinput" onkeyup={handleNewAddress}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-var-p-horizental_small">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-2">
                                <div>
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders"
                                        for="input-05">{textTownCity}</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <lightning-input type="text" id="input-05" placeholder="e.g Newyork" name="city"
                                            required message-when-value-missing={textReqTownCity} class="Myinput"
                                            onkeyup={handleNewAddress}></lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-2">
                                <div>
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label textHeaders"
                                        for="input-06">{textPostalZip}</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <lightning-input type="text" id="input-06" placeholder="e.g xt1234" required
                                            message-when-value-missing={textReqPostalZip} name="zipcode" class="Myinput"
                                            onkeyup={handleNewAddress}>
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <lightning-combobox class="Myinput" name="country" placeholder="e.g Canada"
                                    options={pickListValues} label={textCompanyCountry} required
                                    message-when-value-missing={textReqCountry} onchange={handleNewAddress}>
                                </lightning-combobox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkPosition"><a onclick={hideScreen} class="linkText"> {textExistingAddress}</a></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Buttons component where the buttons enabled disabled based on shipping component input values**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import createACase from '@salesforce/apex/portalGetCaseRecord.createACase';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, APPLICATION_SCOPE, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import dxMessageChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/dxMessageChannel__c';

export default class buttonSection extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track buttonDisabled = true;
  @track currentPageName;
  @api caliberaterecid;
  @api repairrecid;
  @api productId;
  @api textCountinueButton='Continue';
  @api textBackToDashboard='Back to dashboard';
  @api textBack='Back';

  recordId;
  theProduct;
  sourceSystem;
  recordTypeSelect;
  calibrationSelected;
  calibrationValue;
  servicePrioritySelected;
  servicePriorityValue;
  addressSelected;
  addressValue;
  fileSelected;
  fileName = null;
  fileData = null;
  description = null;
  createNewShippingRec;
  backButtonText;

  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  getpageRef(pageRef) {
    this.currentPageName = pageRef.attributes.name;
    if (this.currentPageName === 'Registered_Product_List__c') {
      this.backButtonText = this.textBackToDashboard;
    } else {
      this.backButtonText = this.textBack;
    }
    this.productId = pageRef.state.product_Id;
  }

  @wire(MessageContext) context;

  connectedCallback() {
    this.subscribeMsg();
  }

  subscribeMsg() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      return;
    }
    this.subscription = subscribe(this.context, dxMessageChannel, (message) => this.handleMessage(message), {
      scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE,
    });
  }

  handleMessage(message) {
    if (
      this.currentPageName === 'Registered_Product_List__c' ||
      this.currentPageName === 'registered_product_list__c'
    ) {
      this.theProduct = message.product;
      this.buttonDisabled = false;
    } else if (this.currentPageName === 'Case_Type__c' || this.currentPageName === 'case_type__c') {
      this.recordTypeSelect = message.userSelected;
      if (this.recordTypeSelect === 1 || this.recordTypeSelect === 3) {
        this.buttonDisabled = false;
      } else {
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }
    } else if (this.currentPageName === 'Create_A_Case__c' || this.currentPageName === 'create_a_case__c') {
      if (message.processIndicator === 'caseDescription') {
        this.description = message.userSelected;
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'caseFile') {
        if (message.fileName !== null) {
          this.fileSelected = true;
          this.fileName = message.fileName;
          this.fileData = message.fileData;
        } else {
          this.fileSelected = false;
          this.fileName = null;
          this.fileData = null;
        }
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'CalibrationType') {
        if (this.calibrationValue === message.userSelected) {
          this.calibrationSelected = false;
          this.calibrationValue = null;
        } else {
          this.calibrationSelected = true;
          this.calibrationValue = message.userSelected;
        }
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'ServicePriorities') {
        if (this.servicePriorityValue === message.userSelected) {
          this.servicePrioritySelected = false;
          this.servicePriorityValue = null;
        } else {
          this.servicePrioritySelected = true;
          this.servicePriorityValue = message.userSelected;
        }
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'ShippingSelected') {
        if (this.addressValue === message.userSelected) {
          this.addressSelected = false;
          this.addressValue = null;
          this.createNewShippingRec = false;
        } else {
          this.addressSelected = true;
          this.addressValue = message.userSelected;
          this.createNewShippingRec = false;
        }
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'ShippingManualInputted') {
        this.addressSelected = true;
        this.addressValue = message.userSelected;
        this.createNewShippingRec = true;
      } else if (message.processIndicator === 'AddressSwitch') {
        this.addressSelected = false;
        this.addressValue = null;
        this.createNewShippingRec = false;
      }

      //next process
      let typeName = sessionStorage.getItem('CaseRecordTypeName');

      if (typeName === 'Repair And Calibration' && typeName !== undefined) {
        if (
          this.addressSelected === true &&
          this.servicePrioritySelected === true &&
          this.calibrationSelected === true &&
          this.description !== null &&
          this.description !== ''
        ) {
          this.buttonDisabled = false;
        } else {
          this.buttonDisabled = true;
        }
      } else if (typeName === 'Repair' && typeName !== undefined) {
        if (
          this.addressSelected === true &&
          this.servicePrioritySelected === true &&
          this.description !== null &&
          this.description !== ''
        ) {
          this.buttonDisabled = false;
        } else {
          this.buttonDisabled = true;
        }
      } else if (typeName === 'Calibration' && typeName !== undefined) {
        if (this.addressSelected === true && this.calibrationSelected === true) {
          this.buttonDisabled = false;
        } else {
          this.buttonDisabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  createTheCase() {
    const regProduct = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('meggerORDProduct'));
    const arecordType = sessionStorage.getItem('CaseRecordTypeId');
    const fullShippingAddress = JSON.parse(this.addressValue);

    createACase({
      assetId: regProduct.recordId,
      recordType: arecordType,
      description: this.description,
      filename: this.fileName,
      fileblob: this.fileData,
      calibration: this.calibrationValue,
      services: this.servicePriorityValue,
      address1: fullShippingAddress.Address_Line_1__c,
      address2: fullShippingAddress.Address_Line_2__c,
      address3: fullShippingAddress.Address_Line_3__c,
      town: fullShippingAddress.Town,
      country: fullShippingAddress.Country__c,
      zipcode: fullShippingAddress.Address__PostalCode__s,
      createShipping: this.createNewShippingRec,
      companyName: fullShippingAddress.Name,
      addrId: fullShippingAddress.Id,
    })
      .then((result) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('CaseId', result.Id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('CaseNumber', result.CaseNumber);
        this.error = undefined;
        this.goToFinalPage();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('the case creation error = ' + error);
      });
  }

  goToFinalPage() {
    this.buttonDisabled = true;
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'comm__namedPage',
      attributes: {
        name: 'Case_Details_Submitted__c',
      },
    });
  }

  unsubscribeMC() {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription);
    this.subscription = null;
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.unsubscribeMC();
  }

  navigateBack() {
    if (this.currentPageName === 'case_type__c' || this.currentPageName === 'Case_Type__c') {
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
          name: 'Registered_Product_List__c',
        },
      });
    } else if (this.currentPageName === 'create_a_case__c' || this.currentPageName === 'Create_A_Case__c') {
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
          name: 'Case_Type__c',
        },
      });
    } else if (
      this.currentPageName === 'registered_product_list__c' ||
      this.currentPageName === 'Registered_Product_List__c'
    ) {
      console.log('Inside Reg Product');
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
          name: 'Home',
        },
      });
    }
  }

  navigateNext() {
    if (
      this.currentPageName === 'Registered_Product_List__c' ||
      this.currentPageName === 'registered_product_list__c'
    ) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('meggerORDProduct', JSON.stringify(this.theProduct));
      this.buttonDisabled = true;
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
          name: 'Case_Type__c',
        },
      });
    } else if (this.currentPageName === 'case_type__c' || this.currentPageName === 'Case_Type__c') {
      if (
        sessionStorage.getItem('CaseRecordTypeId') !== undefined &&
        sessionStorage.getItem('CaseRecordTypeId') !== null
      ) {
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: 'comm__namedPage',
          attributes: {
            name: 'Create_A_Case__c',
          },
        });
      }
    } else if (this.currentPageName === 'create_a_case__c' || this.currentPageName === 'Create_A_Case__c') {
      this.createTheCase();
    }
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <div class="slds-col">
      <button
        class="slds-button slds-button_text-destructive slds-float_left slds-p-left_medium slds-p-right_medium slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-p-top_xx-small buttonBordered"
        onclick={navigateBack}>{backButtonText}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-col_bump-left">
      <button
        class="slds-button continue slds-button_neutral slds-float_right slds-p-left_medium slds-p-right_medium slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-p-top_xx-small buttonSolid"
        disabled={buttonDisabled} onclick={navigateNext}>{textCountinueButton}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you are capturing the values from the screen, you are using the handleNewAddress as listening to the event keyup, and when google auto-populates it the event is not triggered, so the values are going as null to the backend, and probably the error is a validation rule saying is required.

My recommendation is to you change your saveAddressRecord method to capture all inputs from the DOM ->

```js
    saveAddressRecord() {
        const lstUserInput = [... this.template.querySelectorAll('lighting-input')]
        let objInputNameInputValue = lstUserInput.reduce( (obj ,element) => {
            return {... obj, [element.name]: element.value }
        }, {});
        console.log(JSON.stringify(objInputNameInputValue ));
        let params = {
            Address1: objInputNameInputValue.address1,
            //TODO finish params
        }
        saveAddressRecord( params )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.hideScreen();
        })         
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Elivelton Walter for your recommendation. Let me change it and see how it works.

Comment: @GiriK did it solved your problem?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Your solution solved the issue. However, I found the root cause. Actually, in the template `onkeyup` event type has been used for the input fields. That was the reason the event not fired when the input field was filled by auto-populated values. I changed it to `onchange` event type which solved the issue. Anyways, thank you very much once again!

Comment: Sorry for my solution to not be clear that info, thank you